# RANKX in measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 2 columns: client and product_name.

I need to number the product_name for each client

| client | product_name | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1 |
| 1 | baa | 2 |
| 1 | cwe | 3 |
| 2 | te | 1 |
| 3 | aaa | 1 |
| 3 | cwq | 2 |

I created a column

```
RANKX_column = 
   RANKX(
   FILTER(Query1,Query1[client_id] = EARLIER(Query1[client_id])),
   Query1[product_id],,ASC,Dense
   )
```

but if I apply a filter, the rank is not recalculated.

I tried to rewrite this formula for measure, but it returns an error about the function EARLIER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
=
VAR ThisClientID =
    MIN( Query1[client_id] )
RETURN
    RANKX(
        FILTER( ALL( Query1 ), Query1[client_id] = ThisClientID ),
        CALCULATE( MIN( Query1[product_id] ) ),
        ,
        ASC,
        DENSE
    )
```

Comment: ... and if you replace ALL with ALLSELECTED it will even recalculate the rank, if a filter is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do it using Power Query:

You need first to group by columns [Client] -- See picture:

[image: GROUP BY]

Resulting Table:

[image: AllDAtTA]

Then create a custom column, Here is the M Code:

```
Table.AddIndexColumn([AllData],"Rank",1,1)
```

[image: CColumn]

Resulting Table:

[image: DERS]

Then Combine (Union) the all tables using The M Code:

```
= Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Rank])
```

[image: RETFG]

Then close & apply. Return to your Main menu:

If you check your data view , The table there seems:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how a table column is less static than a calculated column: It won't recalculate on a different filter selection.

Comment: It will recalculate if you make filter operation in the right query step.

Comment: PQ will recalculate on data refresh only.